# Android, не хочет отображать Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

Поставили мне задачу добавить в старое приложение (2015 года) Navigation Drawer. После добавления активити соответсвующего  выдает следующее

```
'The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).   at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:248)   at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:218)   at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:153)   at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:81)   at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:212)   at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:201)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1123)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1097)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:501)'
```

Подскажите пожалуйста чего куда? Только начал изучать программирование... Хотя бы направьте где почитать... Пробоавл делать миграцию до androidx, нифига не дало

Comment: Ну там написано, что стиль должен быть AppCompat. Попробуй для начала это.

Comment: Это в манифесте прописать для актвити?

Comment: В обшем в манифесте поменял theme у активити новой на android:theme="@style/AppTheme". Начало норм показывать. Ничо не понял чего почему, но сработало